# Sqlite3 Subquery parameterization

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm working with Sqlite3 in Python 3.3. I'm trying to run the following query:

```
c.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO system (id, date,code,number) VALUES 
((select id from system where date=:date, code=:thiscode), :date,:thiscode, 
coalesce((select profiles from system where date=:date, code=:thiscode), 1))', 
{"date": mdate, "thiscode": thiscode})
```

The table is to track the number of instances of a code occurring during a month. If the months' date/code combination already exists, then add 1 to it's number, otherwise create it with number=1.

The error given is an unhelpful

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

I'm guessing the cause involves subquery parameterization since I haven't seen examples of others using it, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: The Python DB-API specifies "paramstyle"s for database modules. The `sqlite3` paramstyle is `?`. Have you tried running your query using the `?` symbol as your parameter placeholder?

Comment: Like self.c.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO system (id, date,code,number) VALUES ((select id from system where date=?, code=?), ?,?,coalesce((select number from system where date=?, code=?), 1))', (mdate, thiscode, mdate, thiscode, mdate, thiscode))  ? That also doesn't work. Same Error as before. Also, due to the repetition, named parameters seemed like a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where date=:date, code=:thiscode
```

What does this mean?
I guess you wanted to write this instead:

```
where date=:date and code=:thiscode
```